iOS review issue: Login Services
I’m trying to submit my first app to the Apple Store. It’s a simple React Native Expo app with Google Login. I’m not sure what to do to fix this issue I received from the review:

The previous issue remained. The app uses a third-party login service,
but does not appear to offer an equivalent login option with the
following features:

The login option limits data collection to the user’s name and email address.
The login option allows users to keep their email address private as part of setting up their account.
The login option does not collect interactions with the app for advertising purposes without consent.


I already have the scopes defined in the code:
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId:
    "999999999999.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  scopes: ["profile", "email"],
});



Essentially they want you to support Sign In With Apple. The App Store review guidelines no longer state this explicitly because of legal challenges. You can use any login service that meets the stated requirements, but Sign In With Apple meets the requirements. Google sign in does not. See clause 4.8

I agree with @Paulw11
they want you to integrate sign In with apple

thank you guys.. I still have issues but not that one anymore!
